# Выбор текстового файла из имеющихся

Tags: delphi

Как сделать список существующих файлов в определенной папке, чтобы можно было выбрать один из них через интерфейс, вместо того чтобы писать полный путь до него.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: TOpenFileDialog?

Comment: findfirst, findnext, findclose - получение списка файлов в папке. потом все это добавить в TListbox

Comment: Открытие файла через стандартный диалог открытия файла вас не устраивает? Вы хотите выбирать только из списка определенных файлов, лежащих в определенном месте? Уточните, пожалуйста, в вопросе.